# Continue program execution with default value if no input given

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am creating a selenium script to automatically fill credential on some website. Now i want to fill multiple credentials, so i have created a `dict` with various profiles and their credentials. So every user just has to select his profile at the start of the script.

A sample `dict` is something like this:

```
credentials = {
'Default': ['default_user', 'default_password'],
'Adam': ['adam_user', 'adam_password'],
'Linus': ['linus_user', 'linus_password']}
```

Now, whenever the script starts it asks the user to choose any profile.

```
Choose your profile:
1. Default
2. Adam
3. Linus
```

Coming to the point, i want the script to autoselect the default profile in case of `no input`, now before you start writing answers let me elaborate.

I mean no input in the sense that the user is afk(away from keyboard), NOT that the user pressed enter and sent empty input, so the script should ask to select a profile and in case there is no input for let's assume 5 seconds, the script should move ahead with the default profile.

I want it to work like this, so that i can schedule it to run at any time(irrespective of the fact that i am asleep) on my local machine and do whatever i want it to.

Any help is appreciated, thanks for reading till the end.

Comment: What operating system are you using? I suspect that solutions might not be cross-platform.

Comment: Parrot os(Linux)

Comment: I just need a way for the python script to move on with the default value after 5 seconds. Don't worry about OS i am on Dual-boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Linux, you can use `signal.alarm` to arrange for an alarm signal to be sent after a certain number of seconds.  Provided that you are not already using alarms for some other purpose, you could use this to make a function that is the equivalent of `input` but that will return some default value after a given timeout.  For example:

```
import signal

class Alarmed(Exception):
    pass

def handle_alarm(signo, frame):
    raise Alarmed
    
def input_with_timeout(prompt, timeout, default):

    # set SIGALRM handler and save any existing one
    old_alarm_handler = signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handle_alarm)

    # arrange for an alarm after specified number of seconds
    signal.alarm(timeout)

    try:
        answer = input(prompt)
    except Alarmed:
        print()
        return default
    finally:
        # switch off any remaining alarm
        signal.alarm(0)
        # restore orig handler
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, old_alarm_handler)  

    return answer


credentials = {
    'Default': ['default_user', 'default_password'],
    'Adam': ['adam_user', 'adam_password'],
    'Linus': ['linus_user', 'linus_password']}

key = input_with_timeout('Choose your profile: ', 5, 'Default')

# non-existent key gives the default also
print('you have chosen ', credentials.get(key, 'Default'))
```

If the process receives the signal `SIGALRM`, then `handle_alarm` is run, which raises our custom exception `Alarmed`.  Note that the clearup code in the `finally` block will get run whether an alarm signal is received or not (and if it is, then it will get run just before the `return`).

Try entering `Adam`, or not typing anything at all.

Adjust the calling code as necessary if you want to enter numerical values.

(With some additional checks, the code could be modified to deal with the situation if we are in fact using `alarm` for another purpose. The call to `signal.alarm` will return the remaining time until any previously set up alarm signal was due to be delivered, if there was one. We are ignoring this return value, but it could be used to detect an existing scheduled alarm, and requeue the original alarm signal minus any elapsed time in the cleanup code after reinstalling the original handler. Some decision would need to be made about what to do if the original alarm was due to be delivered sooner than the requested timeout.)

Comment: It seems like a bit too much, don't get me wrong but isn't there a shorter way(without importing libraries) for this?

Comment: @anantdark I don't know of any. If there is, then perhaps somebody will say.